# Slow evaluation of derivative of Solution of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, procedural-programming

I need to perform a Fourier Transform on the results of a `ParametricNDSolve` function as well as on the derivative of one of the coefficients. Now I do this by evaluating the interpolation function. This is awfully slow and I don't know if there is any faster approach. Maybe you can help me out.

This is essentially my current approach with `c1` being a coefficient in my `NDSolve` solution `fermiD` and `c1'` its derivative :

```
x2 = Table[Evaluate[{c1'[2*Pi*0.001][t]} /. fermiD[[1]]], {t, 3000, 1/10}]
```

In my code I loop it, because I need to evaluate at different frequencies. But I first tried looping one time. The equation are a system of linear differential equations.

```
fermiD = ParametricNDSolve[{equ, equ1}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, {t, 0, tn},{wp}]

For[i = 1, i < 1 + 1, i++, 
  {m = 2*Pi*i*0.001, 
   Print[m], 
   x1 = Table[Evaluate[{c1[m][t]} /. fermiD[[1]]], {t, 0, 3000, 1/10}],
   x2 = 2*Table[Evaluate[{c1'[m][t]} /. fermiD[[1]]], {t, 3000, 1/10}],
   Print["data2"],
   data1 - data2,
   Print["data"],
   Export[StringJoin[{ToString[m], ".txt"}], data]
  }
]
```

Comment: Show us the NDSolve expression and equations you used. I don’t understand the structure of your results from what you showed,

Comment: Does that help or did you mean the whole system of linear equations

Comment: Without complete code, sometimes what you imagine will work won't in fact.  It looks to me like you should have `c1[2*Pi*0.001]'[t]` instead of `c1'[2*Pi*0.001][t]`.

Comment: I would describe `c1` as a solution of your equation rather than a coefficient. To expand on @Michael's comment, `c1'[w][t]` is the first derivative of `c1` with respect to the parameter `w`, whereas `c1[w]'[t]` is the first derivative with respect to your independent variable `t`. From what we gather, you seem to want the latter. Is that right? Also, 1) [avoid `For` loops altogether](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951); try `Table` or `Map` instead; 2) you should separate commands with `;`, instead of enclosing them in braces and separating them with commas.